# How to share cloud stored folders intelligently

Tags: file-sharing, online-storage

I have a paid 50GB cloud storage account and a coworker uses a free 2GB account.

I shared a big folder from the 50GB accont with him, but now he runs out of space on his account and he would have to upgrade to 50GB or leave the shared folder.

This means that each dropbox user has to pay the shared folder's space?

Does this mean if I share this with 5 people, 5 people have to pay for the same content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately yes. The [request](https://www.dropbox.com/votebox/34/share-folders-without-forcing-other-members-to-lose-space) to resolve this issue is pretty high in the Dropbox Votebox. Please vote for it.

You could try alternatives to Dropbox like [Wuala](http://www.wuala.com/en) or [SpiderOak](https://spideroak.com/). In these applications the shared space is taken only from the user that started the sharing. The privacy features are better too.